# Make UIImage clipsToBound over UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` with a static table cell.

And I'm trying to make a cell With `UIImageView` and this image `clipToBounds` to this cell but it's not working.

This is a sample that I want to do.

[image]

But when I make a `UITableView` and set UIImage **clipToBounds** to **TRUE**

the result is :

[image]

Am I just need a way to make `UIImageView` like the first image anyway to do that with `UITableView` Cell?

And this is my UIImageView Constraints :

[image]

and here's my code :

```
class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()



        // image view 

       self.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImage.frame.width / 2
       self.userImage.clipsToBounds = true




    }
```

// MARK: - Table view data source

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    var number = 0

    if section == 0
    {
        number = 1
    }else if section == 1
    {
        number = 4
    }else if section == 2
    {
        number = 1
    }

    return number 
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100 
}

}
```

Comment: As far as I can see image is clipped okay (if the white background represents one cell and the grey rest of the view). You should check for the constraints and UIImageView positioning.

Comment: Can u tell me which portion in your output image is tableViewCell. I mean full image or white portion

Comment: @Adamsor i updated my question check the last image that's show image constraints

Comment: @RahulDasgupta the cell is the view with white background and the image is a subview from the cell

Comment: @Muhammed: All 3 layer's (gray+white+gray) creating a single cell right?

Comment: yes it's only a single static cell

Comment: if you are using static cell then no need to create these delegate. create it directly from storyboard.

Comment: if you are using delegates this delegates I guess thats the reason your code not working..

Comment: yea i created it directly from storyboard

Comment: i found the solution ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution when i added this method and add custom Section header

and give it clipToBounds = false

problem solved

i'm just added :

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.clipsToBounds = false

        return view
    }
```

and it's working perfectly :))

thanks all for trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

Why `clipsToBounds = true` ? 
If the image must be `outside` the cell, then I guess you want the opposite:

```
yourView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 1):

just create outlet for image view make it corner radius itswidth/2 (make sure height and width same size) and make clip to bounds true. for ex:

```
imageView = imageView.frame.size.width/2;
imageView.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem. In cell for row at indexPath

```
let height = CGFloat(cell.frame.size.height-10)
let leading = (cell.frame.size.width - height)/2
let top = CGFloat(18)

let myImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: leading, y: top, width: height, height:height))
myImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
myImage.layer.cornerRadius = (height)/2
cell.contentView.addSubview(myImage)
```

//OR

```
cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myImage.frame.width / 2
cell.myImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jodyw.png)

[image]

[image]